# Use variable in where clause only if NOT empty? A kind of dynamic where clause?

Tags: linq, dynamic, where-clause

Is it possible to include a clause in the where (LINQ) but only if its "NOT" empty ?

i.e.

```
  where c.Code == sCode && p.Code == code
```

In this case the variable (standard c#) is called code ... if its NOT empty then the above where is great.. but if its empty then i don't want to include in it the where

i.e.

```
  where c.Code == sCode
```

In SQL its done like this

```
       AND ( ( @code = '' )
                  OR ( @code <> ''
                       AND C.Code = @code
                     )
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
where c.Code == sCode && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code) || p.Code == code)
```

That's for standard LINQ, I have no idea if it works for LINQ to SQL.

Edit:
This works through [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

if `c.Code == sCode` is false, it stops evaluating and returns false
otherwise, if `string.IsNullOrEmpty(code)` is true, it stops evaluating and returns true
otherwise, return `p.Code == code`

Comment: Hahah ninja style, gotta love how "edits" don't show up unless its after 5 minutes or so of answering a question.

Comment: Great! it works... so if string.IsNullOrEmpty returns true it actually is like this where c.Code == sCode && true - I presume when LINQ sees true in a where clause it ignores it?

Comment: is this linq to sql? if so, best way is to run a sql profiler trace (or use a lesser-known method called `.ToTraceString()`)

Answer (score 4):

Put that in an `IQueryable<T>` extension method to keep it really simple:

```
public static IQueryable<Code> WithCodeIfNotEmpty(this IQueryable<Code> source, string code)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
      return source;
   else
      return source.Where(x => x.Code == code);
}
```

Usage:

```
var query = something.WithCodeIfNotEmpty("someCode");
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated by others :

```
(string.IsNullOrEmpty(code) || p.Code == code)
```

btw sql can be optimised to

```
   C.Code = isnull(ltrim(rtrim(@code)), c.Code)
```

Comment: Thanks Preet .. This is very good and simple solution to the problem i am facing. I asked a post myself and people just answered DLinq and ext methods .. all i wanted is your solution ..

Answer (score 0):

If you want a direct translation form that TSQL you given then this is the answer

```
where
  code == "" ||
  (code != "" &&
  c.Code == code)
```